# Binary Search returns negative values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a list of Series and a vertical annotation. I want to have the Y value of the signals for every X position of the vertical annotation (VA).

Here is what I have done so far.

```
VerticalAnnotation VA;                
List<double> Points = new List<double>();

foreach (var sig in Signals)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < sig.Points.Count; g++)
    {
        Points.Add(sig.Points[g].XValue);
    }
    Points.Sort();
}
```

and

```
private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
{
    var x = Points.BinarySearch(VA.X);
}
```

But for some reason x variable gets negative values which does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch) say this:

> Returns ... the zero-based index of item in the sorted List, if item is found; **otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item** or, if there is no larger element, **the bitwise complement of Count**

Note that the latter value is also negative.

A negative result means that what you are looking for is not in the list. Also the result can be used (by inverting it as `~result`) to know where the value at hand *would* have been found if it had been in the list, or where you would need to insert it to keep the list nicely sorted.

Comment: so the problem is that the vertical annotation goes to areas between the datapoints and these values are not in the list. I guess I need to find a way for the vertical annotation either to move only across datapoints or to get the nearest datapoint's value.